# Python regular expression works in Python 2 but not in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, macos

```
expression = re.compile(ur'\?(.*)')
```

The expression is simple and this project was originally built on a Mac. It runs fine in Python 2 on the Mac, however it doesn't run on Windows (Python 3) failing with

```
File "path/to/scrapy/spiders/spider.py", line 42
expression = re.compile(ur'\?(.*)')
                                 ^
```

Comment: Have you tried retyping the quotes on your Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about Mac vs Windows, I suspect, *it is about the Python version you are using to run this code on*.

When I run this code on Python 2.7 - it runs fine, no problems. On Python 3.5 I get a `SyntaxError` (cause of the `u` prefix, of course):

```
  File "/Users/user/SO/test.py", line 3
    expression = re.compile(ur'\?(.*)')
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Check that you are actually using Python 2 on both machines.